# How To set Pan Gesture Limit in swift 3

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I take two view and in that view i take image view..show..Below

[image]

i need to set limit, image centre that not going to out side of the super view..

i am trying that code but that not work proper some time work proper..

```
func panImage(tap:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let minx = (abs(Int((tap.view?.superview?.center.x)!)) - ((Int((tap.view?.superview?.frame.width)!))/2))
    let maxx = (abs(Int((tap.view?.superview?.center.x)!)) + ((Int((tap.view?.superview?.frame.width)!))/2))
    let miny = (abs(Int((tap.view?.superview?.center.y)!)) - ((Int((tap.view?.superview?.frame.height)!))/2))
    let maxy = (abs(Int((tap.view?.superview?.center.y)!)) + ((Int((tap.view?.superview?.frame.height)!))/2))
    let translation = tap.translation(in: tap.view)
    if(Int(tap.view!.center.x) > maxx)
    {tap.view!.center.x = CGFloat(maxx)}
    if(Int(tap.view!.center.x) < minx)
    {tap.view!.center.x = CGFloat(minx)}
    if(Int(tap.view!.center.y) > maxy)
    {tap.view!.center.y = CGFloat(maxy)}
    if(Int(tap.view!.center.y) < miny)
    {tap.view!.center.y = CGFloat(miny)}

    if((Int(tap.view!.center.x) >= minx && Int(tap.view!.center.x) <= maxx ) && (Int(tap.view!.center.y) <= maxy && Int(tap.view!.center.y) >= miny))
    {
        tap.view!.center = CGPoint(x: tap.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: tap.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        tap.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), in:tap.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you solve the ptoblem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am try that code that work proper..

here

```
 func panImage(tap:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let minx = 0
    let maxx = minx + Int((tap.view?.superview?.frame.size.width)!)
    let miny = 0
    let maxy = miny + Int((tap.view?.superview?.frame.size.height)!)
    let translation = tap.translation(in: tap.view)
    if(Int(tap.view!.center.x) > maxx)
    {tap.view!.center.x = CGFloat(maxx)}
    if(Int(tap.view!.center.x) < minx)
    {tap.view!.center.x = CGFloat(minx)}
    if(Int(tap.view!.center.y) > maxy)
    {tap.view!.center.y = CGFloat(maxy)}
    if(Int(tap.view!.center.y) < miny)
    {tap.view!.center.y = CGFloat(miny)}

    if((Int(tap.view!.center.x) >= minx && Int(tap.view!.center.x) <= maxx ) && (Int(tap.view!.center.y) <= maxy && Int(tap.view!.center.y) >= miny))
    {
        tap.view!.center = CGPoint(x: tap.view!.center.x + translation.x, y: tap.view!.center.y + translation.y)
        tap.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), in:tap.view)
    }
}
```